# Dask multiprocessing fails with embarrassingly parallel for loop including call to MongoDB when number of iterations is high enough

Tags: windows, mongodb, python-3.x, dask

I'm trying to run a kind of simulation in Python for loop in parallel using Dask multiprocessing. Parallelization works fine when number of iterations is fairly low but fails when the amount increases. The issue occurs on Win7 (4 cores, 10 Gb RAM), Win10 (8 cores, 8 Gb RAM) and Azure VM running Windows Server 2016 (16 cores, 32 Gb RAM). The slowest one, Win7, can go through most iterations before failing. The issue can be mitigated by adding long enough sleep time at the end of each function included in the process, but the required amount of sleeping results in very low performance, similar to running sequentially.

I hope someone will be able to help me out here. Thanks in advance for comments and answers!

The following simple code contains some phases of the for loop and repeats the error.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create random DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))

# Save to Mongo
client = MongoClient()
db = client.errordemo
res = db.errordemo.insert_many(json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records')))
db.client.close()


class ToBeRunParallel:

def __init__(self):
    pass

def functionToBeRunParallel(self, i):

    # Read data from mongo
    with MongoClient() as client:
        db = client.errordemo
        dataFromMongo = pd.DataFrame.from_records(db.errordemo.find({}, {'_id': 0}))

    # Randomize data
    dataRand = dataFromMongo.apply(pd.to_numeric).apply(rand, volatility=0.1)

    # Sum rows
    dataSum = dataRand.sum(axis=1)

    # Select randomly one of the resulting values and return
    return dataSum.sample().values[0]
```

Call the function functionToBeRunParallel either in console or Jupyter (both fail). 'errordemo' is a local module containing the class ToBeRunParallel. While running the on Azure VM, the code succeeds with 500 loops and fails with 5,000.

```
import errordemo
from dask import delayed, compute, multiprocessing

# Determine how many times to loop
rng = range(15000)

# Define empty result lists
resList = []

# Create instance
err = errordemo.ToBeRunParallel()

# Loop in parallel using Dask
for i in rng:
    sampleValue = delayed(err.functionToBeRunParallel)(i)
    resList.append(sampleValue)

# Compute in parallel 
result = compute(*resList, get=multiprocessing.get)
```

The error stack in Jupyter is as follows.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AutoReconnect                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9f535dd4c621> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', '# Determine how many times to loop\nrng = range(50000)\n\n# Define empty result lists\nresList = []\n\n# Create instance\nerr = errordemo.ToBeRunParallel()\n\n# Loop in parallel using Dask\nfor i in rng:\n    sampleValue = delayed(err.functionToBeRunParallel)(i)\n    resList.append(sampleValue)\n    \n# Compute in parallel \nresult = compute(*resList, get=dask.multiprocessing.get)')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2113             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2114             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2115                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2116             return result
   2117 

<decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1178         else:
   1179             st = clock2()
-> 1180             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1181             end = clock2()
   1182             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    200     dsk = collections_to_dsk(variables, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
    201     keys = [var._keys() for var in variables]
--> 202     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    203 
    204     results_iter = iter(results)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\multiprocessing.py in get(dsk, keys, num_workers, func_loads, func_dumps, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
     85         result = get_async(pool.apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk3, keys,
     86                            get_id=_process_get_id,
---> 87                            dumps=dumps, loads=loads, **kwargs)
     88     finally:
     89         if cleanup:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, raise_on_exception, rerun_exceptions_locally, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    498                     _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    499                 else:
--> 500                     raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
    501             state['cache'][key] = res
    502             finish_task(dsk, key, state, results, keyorder.get)

AutoReconnect: localhost:27017: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Traceback
---------
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 266, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 247, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "C:\Git_repository\footie\Pipeline\errordemo.py", line 20, in functionToBeRunParallel
    dataFromMongo = pd.DataFrame.from_records(db.errordemo.find({}, {'_id': 0}))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 981, in from_records
    first_row = next(data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1090, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1012, in _refresh
    self.__read_concern))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 850, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 844, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 855, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 163, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 582, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket_no_auth()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 618, in _get_socket_no_auth
    sock_info, from_pool = self.connect(), False
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 555, in connect
    _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 65, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise AutoReconnect(msg)
```

UPDATE:

Following [this post](http://www.arngarden.com/2013/04/29/handling-mongodb-autoreconnect-exceptions-in-python-using-a-proxy/), I created a decorator to catch AutoReconnect exception like shown below. Together with parameters for MongoClient the looping works, but it's still very slow, double the time it should take. (timing on the Azure VM):

500 iterations: 3.74s
50,000 iterations: 12min 12s

```
def safe_mongocall(call):
    def _safe_mongocall(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(5):
            try:
                return call(*args, **kwargs)
            except errors.AutoReconnect:
                sleep(random.random() / 100)
        print('Error: Failed operation!')
    return _safe_mongocall

@safe_mongocall
def functionToBeRunParallel(self, i):

    # Read data from mongo
    with MongoClient(connect=False, maxPoolSize=None, maxIdleTimeMS=100) as client:
         db = client.errordemo
         dataFromMongo = pd.DataFrame.from_records(db.errordemo.find({}, {'_id': 0}))

    # Randomize data
    dataRand = dataFromMongo.apply(pd.to_numeric).apply(rand, volatility=0.1)

    # Sum rows
    dataSum = dataRand.sum(axis=1)

    # Select randomly one of the resulting values and return
    return dataSum.sample().values[0]
```

Comment: I wonder if this is possibly due to making thousands of MongoClients.   You might try closing the MongoClient in the function.  Perhaps using it as a context manager like `with MongoClient() as client:`.  More generally, it would be useful to see if this fails only with Dask and without MongoDB.

Comment: Doesn't "db.client.close()" close MongoClient? I'll give it a try without Mongo.

Comment: It is MongoDB related: looping works when operations are done to an existing dataframe. However, using MongoClient as context manager doesn't solve the issue. I edited headline to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: Can you post the manner of the failure you see? Is it possible that you sometimes have an exception at `from_records`, so the client doesn't get closes? A context manager or try/finally could account for that.

Comment: Added error stack to the description. Try/finally doesn't do the trick,  I have them in the actual code.

Comment: Does this fail if you don't use multiprocessing?  What if you use the single-threaded scheduler `compute(..., get=dask.async.get_sync)`

Comment: Single-threaded scheduler works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue is exhausting of TCP/IP ports, hence the solution is to avoid exhaustion. Following [article by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx), I added the following registry keys and values to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters:

MaxUserPort: 65534
TcpTimedWaitDelay: 30